# TDTM deployment failing with 0% coverage

Tags: unit-test, npsp, tdtm

I am trying to deploy a NPSP TDTM trigger for a custom object to production. The trigger works in the sandbox environment, and the test class provides 91% coverage. When I attempt to deploy to production, the trigger apparently never fires, based on the log - the debug statements from the TDTM class don't appear, though those from the test do. One difference I'm aware of between the two environments - the TDTM trigger was installed and running previously in the sandbox, though I've since deactivated it to try to get matching results.

Here is my test class:

```
@isTest (seealldata = true)
public class test_REG_MintLCIs_TDTM {
    
    static testmethod void testRegMint() {
        
        // Retrieve default NPSP Trigger Handlers
        List<npsp__Trigger_Handler__c> triggerHandlers = npsp.TDTM_Config_API.getCachedRecords();
        
        // Add our Trigger Handler to cached Trigger Handlers
        npsp__Trigger_Handler__c th = new npsp__Trigger_Handler__c();
        th.Name = 'MyPAYTriggerHandler';
        th.npsp__Class__c = 'REG_MintLCIs_TDTM';
        th.npsp__Object__c = 'league_event_registration__c';
        th.npsp__Trigger_Action__c = 'BeforeUpdate';
        th.npsp__Active__c = true;
        th.npsp__Load_Order__c = 2;
        th.npsp__Asynchronous__c = false;
        
        insert th;
        
        triggerHandlers.add(th);
        system.debug(th);
        system.debug(triggerhandlers);
        
        // setup our test data...
        
        contact c = [select id from contact where lci_number__c = null and Membership_Expiration__c > :system.today() limit 1];
        
        league_event__c e = new league_event__c();
        e.Name = 'LCI Test';
        e.Event_End__c = system.now()-10;
        insert e;
        
        league_event_registration__c ler = new league_event_registration__c();
        ler.League_Event__c = e.id;
        ler.Registrant__c = c.id;
        insert ler;
        test.startTest();
        ler.Passed_LCI__c = 'Passed';
        update ler;
        test.stopTest();
        contact c_up = [select id, lci_number__c from contact where id = :c.id];
        system.assert(c_up.LCI_Number__c != null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You tagged this question with `[failing-tests]`, but that does not seem to apply here. Does the test actually fail with an error? If so, please [edit] your post to include the message. If not, please remove this tag. You can still apply `[unit-test]` and have it be accurate.

Comment: Do you have an Apex trigger on this object? Did you deploy the trigger? You should also remove `seealldata = true`, since you do not appear to need it and it can change the behavior of your code under test.

Comment: @DavidReed - the trigger was the missing ingredient. I built all of this months ago and had totally forgotten about the trigger for the custom object. I thought it might have been something like that, but hadn't found the right search terms to lead me to the answer. Thank you so much.